# Not able to copy files on SD card

Tags: files, copy

I am not able to copy/move files on SD card, the button is not activ.I don't know why I can't now, whit some time ago was no problem.I tryed to do this using the terminal, the code and error was this:

```
stefan@stefan-desktop:~$ mv /home/stefan/Desktop/tipuri_CD.pdf /media/stefan/46A4-D3FD
mv: inter-device move failed: '/home/stefan/Desktop/tipuri_CD.pdf' to '/media/stefan/46A4-D3FD/tipuri_CD.pdf'; unable to remove target: Read-only file system

stefan@stefan-desktop:~$
```

Comment: You've not provided any OS or release details, nor clues as to what *file-system* was on your media, and how it was mounted. Was it mounted read-only?   If it wasn't (ie. *was mounted RW*), a file-system that *flips* to RO occurs only when errors are detected (*bad media, or logical errors in the file-system*) where flipping to RO prevents data loss.  Check your messages, or logs on your *unstated* OS as to how it was mounted, or if it *flipped*, why it flipped.

Comment: error message is rather explicit `Read-only file system`. is physical protection set on SD card ? have you tried removing/reinserting card ?